# How to read the files inside a directory when Only Relative path of directory is known

Tags: java, file

In my java application, 
1. I have **relative path** of the directory (Directory and files in it are part of the build). 
2.The directory contains multiple files. 
3. I want to read the file names in the parent directory.
4. **Files can change later and are many in number, So I do not know the names of the files and Do not want my code to change if more files are added or removed or renamed**

Now as I do not know the names of the files before hand as they may change later (there are multiple files which can vary according to environment). I only know about the relative path of the parent directory of the files.

How do I read the files ?

Comment: I updated my answer to feet your need please read it again and if helps press accept as an answer and vote

Answer (score 1):

You can get list of all files of that directory by file.getlistFiles() method of file class.
It returns an array of files.
Even you can define filter for your files, so it returns exactly files that you want.

```
try {
    File f = new File("D:/Programming");

    FilenameFilter filter = new FilenameFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File f, String name) {
            // We want to find only .c files
            return name.endsWith(".c");
        }
    };

    // Note that this time we are using a File class as an array,
    // instead of String
    File[] files = f.listFiles(filter);
```

look at [this](https://stackabuse.com/java-list-files-in-a-directory/) example. 
If you want to use relative  path, You can use

```
System.getProperty("user.dir");
String relative  Path =System.getProperty("user.dir");
```

it returns the folder that you put your app in it.
If your folder has some subfolders, you can simply use file.list();
it returns names of all files and folders of your directory .
String [] listOfMyFilesAndFolders =file.list();
you can add these names to your path to access another folders.
You can check your path is a file or is a folder by using

```
file.isDirectory();
for ( String path: listOfFilesAndFolders ) {
File file = new File(basePath+path);
if ( file.isDirectory() {
// it is a folder and you can use another for loop or recursion to navigate sub directories
} else {
// it is  a file and you can do everyThing you want}}
```

I think that you can use recursion to walk in your sub directories use [recursion](https://www.javatpoint.com/recursion-in-java) to read more
    I hope helps.

Comment: 'File("D:/Programming")' Here you have used absolute path. The directory is part of the build and it has child files. I have the relative path of the directory.

Comment: if you want to use relative  path, you can use

Comment: thanks for updating your answer, I will check it with my application. Meanwhile i upvoted it, will accept ince it works on my application...

Answer (score 0):

the question is badly asked and the text is misleading.
"I have relative path of the directory (Directory and files in it are part of the build)" means little and nothing, you have to clarify what you mean.

Assuming you get a relative directory (for example "/folder1/folder2") via command line parameter, you basically have 3 choices:

1) start the program with the directory in which the jar is located as the "current directory", so that it can be used as a working directory. This approach requires that when you launch your application via the java -jar myapp.jar command first you prepend a "cd" command to place yourself directly in the directory. The code will look like the @hamidreza75 solution but obviously you will not have the variable "D: / Programming" but directly the relative path of the directory in which to read the files.

launch script

```
@echo off
cd {jar-folder}
java -jar myapp.jar
```

java code:

```
package com.sample.stack;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;

public class FileRenamenter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String relativePath = "folder1/folder2";
        File directory = new File(relativePath);
        String[] list = directory.list(new FilenameFilter(){
            public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                // filter condition
                return true;
            }
        });
        // echo file list
        for (String filePath : list) {
            System.out.println(filePath);
        }
    }
}
```

2) pass the folder to be controlled via command line parameter, like this:

launch script

```
@echo off
java -jar {jar-folder}/myapp.jar {jar-folder}
```

java code (only the "directory" variable changes)

```
File directory = new File(args[0], relativePath); // note args[0]
```

3) programmatically find the folder in which the jar is running [very discouraged practice] and then concatenate the relative path:

java code (only the "directory" variable changes):

```
String jarFolder = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource(".").getPath();
File directory = new File(jarFolder, relativePath); // note jarFolder
```